# A procedure data for a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, oracle, stored-procedures, datagridview

I have created a Windows Forms application in C# that will make use of a procedure in Oracle database.

In this form there is a `DataGridView` that I intend to bring the data through this procedure, but do not know what is missing in my code for this function, since it does not bring me any data. Below is the code of both:

**Oracle procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE P_TRANSFITENS(vID in NUMBER) is
  cursor vAUX is
    select t.pro_in_codigo,
           t.alm_in_codigo,
           t.loc_in_codigo,
           u.loc_st_nome,
           t.nat_st_codigo,
           t.mvs_re_quantidade,
           t.mvs_st_loteforne
      from bd.est_movsumarizado t, bd.est_almoxlocal u
     where t.pro_in_codigo = vID
       and u.loc_in_codigo = t.loc_in_codigo;
  rDadosItem vAUX%ROWTYPE;  
begin
  open vAUX;
  loop
    fetch vAUX
      into rDadosItem;
    exit when vAUX%NOTFOUND;
  end loop;
  close vAUX;
end;
```

**C# (Button click handler):**

```
OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter();
OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection();
objConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=dtsource;User Id=user;Password=pass";
objConn.Open();
adp.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand();
adp.SelectCommand.Connection = objConn;

adp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "P_TRANSFITENS";
adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@vID", Convert.ToInt32(mskdId.Text)); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
dtgrvDetalhesItem.DataSource = dt;
```

Thanks a lot!

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Execute the procedure manually - do you get any data?

Comment: Yes, with this code    loop
    fetch vAUX
      into rDadosItem;
    exit when vAUX%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line('Código: ' || rDadosItem.alm_in_codigo  ||
                         'Cod Loc: ' || rDadosItem.loc_in_codigo ||
                         'Nome Loc: ' || rDadosItem.loc_st_nome);
  end loop;

Comment: About the last message, nothing with this:  `adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@vID", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(mskdId.Text);`  Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the format should be like

```
PROCEDURE P_TRANSFITENS(vID in NUMBER, _RESULTS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS

BEGIN


    OPEN _RESULTS FOR
       select t.pro_in_codigo,
       t.alm_in_codigo,
       t.loc_in_codigo,
       u.loc_st_nome,
       t.nat_st_codigo,
       t.mvs_re_quantidade,
       t.mvs_st_loteforne
  from bd.est_movsumarizado t, bd.est_almoxlocal u
 where t.pro_in_codigo = vID
   and u.loc_in_codigo = t.loc_in_codigo;

END P_TRANSFITENS;
```

Then you add this

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 OracleParameter refcursor = new OracleParameter("_RESULTS", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
 refcursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(refcursor);
```

Comment: Nice, this solved my problem. I thought it was more complicated  =)  Thanks @codingbiz

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you aren't configure input/output params correctly.

try something like this:

```
OracleParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("vAUX", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleParameter param2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("vID", OracleDbType.Int32);
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```

i'm unable to test it, but maybe, give it a try.

Comment: Even though solved with @codingbiz, I'll test your solution.  Tks!